# Why is $|(iX)^j \exp(itX)|=|X|^j$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I saw this on p. 126 of Rosenthal's *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*
\begin{align}
|(iX)^j \exp(itX)|=|X|^j
\end{align}
I am not sure why this is true though.

Comment: $\exp(i\theta)$ always lies in the unit circle if $\theta$ is real, and the norm of $i$ is also $1$, so...

Comment: Assuming that $X$ and $t$ are real, both $i^j$ and $\exp(itX)$ have magnitude one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity $|ab| = |a| |b|$ works as well for complex numbers as for real numbers, and one has $|i| = 1$ and $\left|\exp(itX)\right|=1$ if $tX$ is real.